# Save image in a folder using relative path in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to save image in a folder using relative path. My code is

```
bmp1.Save(@"~/mintemp/" + filename, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

I'm getting error like this.

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

But when i change path like below

```
bmp1.Save(@"E:\web data\website\mintemp\" + filename, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Code working fine in absolute path. Can anyone help me to solve out this issue becaue i want to save using relative path. Thanks in advance, sorry for my  bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Server.MapPath`. The `MapPath` method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.

Note that, `Server.MapPath(@"~/mintemp/")` returns the physical path of the folder `mintemp` present in the root directory of the application

```
bmp1.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~/mintemp/") + filename, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Server.MapPath` function to get the relative path.

In your case it'll be : `Server.MapPath("E:\web data\website\mintemp\" + filename)`. It return a string that you can use in your `Save` method.

More explanations here : https://forums.asp.net/t/1813648.aspx?Any+difference+between+Server+MapPath+and+Server+MapPath+